# Android Bluetooth MAC, ReOrder/Change

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, root

I am trying to change the single byte of the **Android Bluetooth MAC** address for specific slave requirement.

"00:11:22:AA:BB:**CC**" to "00:11:22:AA:BB:**06**"

Is there any way to archive it.
Slave Device will recognize the last byte of the **Source MAC address / Initiator Address**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Also, starting in Android 6 (API 23) access to hardware identifiers is even more limited: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#version_specific_details_identifiers_in_m